# SQL Server OUTPUT clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, scope-identity, output-clause

I am a little stuck with why I can not seem to get the 'new identity' of the inserted row with the statement below. `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` just returns null.

```
declare @WorkRequestQueueID int
declare @LastException nvarchar(MAX)
set @WorkRequestQueueID = 1
set @LastException = 'test'

set nocount off

DELETE dbo.WorkRequestQueue
OUTPUT
        DELETED.MessageEnvelope,
        DELETED.Attempts,
        @LastException,
        GetUtcdate(), -- WorkItemPoisened datetime
        DELETED.WorkItemReceived_UTC
    INTO dbo.FaildMessages
FROM dbo.WorkRequestQueue
WHERE
    WorkRequestQueue.ID = @WorkRequestQueueID

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
  RAISERROR ('Record not found', 16, 1) 

SELECT Cast(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int)
```

Any assistance would be most appreciated.

For now I use a workaround this like so.

```
declare     @WorkRequestQueueID int
declare @LastException nvarchar(MAX)
set @WorkRequestQueueID = 7
set @LastException = 'test'

set nocount on
set xact_abort on 

DECLARE @Failed TABLE 
(
    MessageEnvelope xml, 
    Attempts smallint,
    LastException nvarchar(max),
    WorkItemPoisened_UTC datetime,
    WorkItemReceived_UTC datetime
)

BEGIN TRAN

DELETE dbo.WorkRequestQueue
OUTPUT
    DELETED.MessageEnvelope,
    DELETED.Attempts,
    @LastException,
    GetUtcdate(), -- WorkItemPoisened datetime
    DELETED.WorkItemReceived_UTC

INTO 
    @Failed
FROM 
    dbo.WorkRequestQueue
WHERE
    WorkRequestQueue.ID = @WorkRequestQueueID

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BEGIN  
    RAISERROR ('Record not found', 16, 1) 
    Rollback
END ELSE BEGIN
    insert into dbo.FaildMessages select * from @Failed
    COMMIT TRAN
    SELECT Cast(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int) 
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try to use a table variable for your `output` clause, thus allowing you to explicitly insert into `FaildMessages`:

```
declare     @WorkRequestQueueID int
declare @LastException nvarchar(MAX)
set @WorkRequestQueueID = 1
set @LastException = 'test'

set nocount off

    -- Declare a table variable to capture output
    DECLARE @output TABLE (
        MessageEnvelope VARCHAR(50),    -- Guessing at datatypes
        Attempts INT,                   -- Guessing at datatypes
        WorkItemReceived_UTC DATETIME   -- Guessing at datatypes
    )

    -- Run the deletion with output
    DELETE dbo.WorkRequestQueue
    OUTPUT
        DELETED.MessageEnvelope,
        DELETED.Attempts,
        DELETED.WorkItemReceived_UTC
    -- Use the table var
    INTO @output
    FROM dbo.WorkRequestQueue
    WHERE
        WorkRequestQueue.ID = @WorkRequestQueueID

    -- Explicitly insert
    INSERT
    INTO dbo.FaildMessages
    SELECT
        MessageEnvelope,
        Attempts,
        @LastException,
        GetUtcdate(), -- WorkItemPoisened datetime
        WorkItemReceived_UTC
    FROM @output


IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
  RAISERROR ('Record not found', 16, 1)


SELECT Cast(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int)
```

Answer (score 4):

**EDITED FEB'2013**

@MartinSmith alerts us that this bug [don't want be fixed by Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/765809/odd-behaviour-of-scope-identity-with-insert-into).

> "Posted by Microsoft on 2/27/2013 at 2:18 PM Hello Martin,  We
> investigated the issue and found that changing the behavior is not an
> easy thing to do. It would basically require redefining some of the
> behavior when both INSERT & OUTPUT INTO target has identity columns.
> Given the nature of the problem & the uncommon scenario, we have
> decided not to fix the issue.    --  Umachandar, SQL Programmability
> Team"

**EDITED OCT'2012**

**This is caused by a bug:**

**Testing bug:**

[Quoting OUTPUT Clause doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx):

> @@IDENTITY, SCOPE_IDENTITY, and IDENT_CURRENT return identity values
> generated only by the nested DML statement, and not those generated by
> the outer INSERT statement.

After test it It seems that scope_identity() only works if outer operation is an insert in a table with identity columns:

Test 1: Delete

```
create table #t ( a char(1) );
create table #d ( a char(1), i int identity );

insert into #t
values ('a'),('b'),('c');

delete #t
output deleted.a into #d;

select SCOPE_IDENTITY(), * from #d;

     a i 
---- - - 
null a 1 
null b 2 
null c 3
```

Test 2: [Inserting in outer table with identity](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/81574?opt.textResults=true)

```
create table #t ( a char(1), i int identity );
create table #d ( a char(1), i int identity );

insert into #t
values  ('x'),('x'),('x');

insert into #t
output inserted.a into #d
values  ('a'),('b');

select scope_identity(), * from #d;

  a i 
- - - 
2 a 1 
2 b 2
```

Test 3: Inserting in outer table without identity

```
create table #t ( a char(1) );
create table #d ( a char(1), i int identity );

insert into #t
values  ('x'),('x'),('x');

insert into #t
output inserted.a into #d
values  ('a'),('b');

select scope_identity(), * from #d;


     a i 
---- - - 
null a 1 
null b 2
```

Comment: @danihp - The reason that `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)` does not work is because the bug report you have found on Connect is not the same one as this. [I have created a new one here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/765809/odd-behaviour-of-scope-identity-with-insert-into)